# How do you assert a test method for apex validation

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a requirement to require a picklist field to be populated if an Opportunity is closed and a certain type of product is used in the Opportunity Product. I wanted to develop something that checks if the product is used in real time and then stop the user in a before update method.

I created this class that works in the UI:

```
public static void eCommValidation(Map<Id, Opportunity> oldMap, Map<Id, Opportunity> newMap)
{
    List<Product2> prods = [SELECT  Id
                            FROM    Product2
                            WHERE   Product_Offering__c = 'Checkout Online' 
                            AND     IsActive = TRUE 
                            AND     Product_LOB__c = 'USA - 3970 - Consumer Technology Consumer'];

    Set<Id> oppys = new Set<Id>();
    ValidationRules__c cs = ValidationRules__c.getInstance();
    Boolean val = cs.Fire_Validation_Rules__c;

    for(Opportunity oppy: newMap.values())
    {
        oppys.addAll(newMap.keySet());
        List<OpportunityLineItem> olis = [SELECT    Id
                                          FROM      OpportunityLineItem
                                          WHERE     Product2Id In: prods 
                                          AND       OpportunityId In: oppys];

        if(
            val &&
            !olis.isEmpty() &&
            String.isBlank(oppy.E_Comm_Was_1st_Price_Accepted__c) &&
            oppy.StageName != oldMap.get(oppy.Id).StageName &&
            (oppy.StageName == 'Closed - Won' ||
             oppy.StageName == 'Closed - Lost')

        )
        {
            oppy.addError(' The stage has been changed to \'Closed - Won\' and an E-Commerce Product has been selected. '+
                           'The \'E-commerce Checkout Client Feedback\' section is now required!');
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm working on my test class. For all my tests I've written in the past the method did things insert/updates/filters so I could return a value and assert that it's what I expect or not.

How do you do an assertion if nothing happens? Here is a test snipit where I'm passing two maps into the class:

```
@isTest static void happyresult()
{
    Map<Id, Opportunity> oppyold = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
    Map<Id, Opportunity> oppynew = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();

    Id tempId = getDummyId();

    oppyold.put(tempId, new Opportunity(
        Name = 'Test', 
        Id = tempId,
        E_Comm_Was_1st_Price_Accepted__c = null
    ));

    oppynew.put(tempId, new Opportunity(
        Name = 'Test', 
        Id = tempId,
        E_Comm_Was_1st_Price_Accepted__c = null,
        StageName = 'Closed - Won'
    ));

    Test.startTest();
        NPD_E_Commerce_Product_Validation.eCommValidation(oppyold, oppynew);
    Test.stopTest();

   System.assert(?,?)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assert that the validation takes place at the service layer. Only at the trigger layer can you do so. Basically, you have to verify this method gets called from your trigger.

```
DmlException expectedException;
Test.startTest();
    try
    {
        // save record which should be prevented from saving
    }
    catch (DmlException d)
    {
        expectedException = d;
    }
Test.stopTest();

system.assertNotEquals(null, expectedException, 'The record should be validated');
```

And for cases where you expect the record to save successfully, you flip the logic:

```
DmlException unexpectedException;
Test.startTest();
    try
    {
        // save record which should save successfully
    }
    catch (DmlException d)
    {
        unexpectedException = d;
    }
Test.stopTest();

system.assertEquals(null, unexpectedException, 'The record should be saved');
```

If it's a complex validation, you should aim to cover each logical path with a separate test method.

Comment: Ahh, assertequals when they should match and notequals when the do not match.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Adrian has stated this is my typical pattern

I assert the message to ensure the right one was thrown and I assert in the try rather than a property that an error was thrown

```
    Test.startTest();
    try
    {
        // insert record which should be validated
        insert new Opportunity(
                Name = 'Test',
                Id = tempId,
                E_Comm_Was_1st_Price_Accepted__c = null,
                StageName = 'Closed - Won'
        );
        //If we make it here omething went wrong a we expected an error
        system.assertEquals(false, 'An error should have been thrown');
    }
    catch (DmlException d)
    {
        //Assert that the message returned was the one you expected. Various ways to do it, this just ensures part of the message is there 
        System.assertEquals(true, d.getDmlMessage().contains('section is now required'),'An unexpected error meage was returned');
    }
    Test.stopTest();
```

You can should also write one where no error is thrown and ensure the record gets updated properly.

If doing multiple record, forgo the try / catch block and use a saveResult to iterate over and assert results

Comment: For the assertion in your `try` block you can just do `system.assert(false, '<message>')`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson -Doh, did not even realize that was there...Old habits I guess. Updated my template to fix that, thanks

Comment: Also the error message is just an implementation detail IMO and really belongs in a `Custom Label` in the long run.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Yup, agree. I like to assert the message especially if there are multiple possible errors then I know the test is actually hitting the error I want and not something else.

Comment: I'm saying I think that's a bit of a rigid test and I usually don't care about the actual message. Usually I just modify the one thing from the happy path that will cause the record to fail. Purely a matter of opinion but it's been an annoyance in the past.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Agreed. To each their own. Rigidity in my current environment has been a life saver for our code base and prevented many issues, and caused a few delay as well :)

Answer (score 2):

In your happy case, I assume that you don't want to add the error to your record(s).

Since you're testing your method independently from a trigger (bravo on that, by the way!), you won't get an exception.

What you can check instead, however, is if `ApexPages` contains any messages. When you call `addError()`, the error is pushed into the page messages for the current context.

Even though the name of the class contains 'Pages', you don't need a visualforce page (or to be in a controller) to access the page messages.

`system.assertEquals(false, ApexPages.hasMessages(), 'Error message was added to record(s) when we didn't expect any error messages);` should be exactly what you're looking for here.